# Seting 0 values in GeoTIFF to nodata using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal

Is there a way to set all the 0 value pixels on a raster to nodata using GDAL?

I would like to use fillnodata to fill some holes, but holes are set to 0, so I need to delete them first

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try something like this with [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: Note: This only works if the raster does not have existing nodata values. It will set zero to be nodata, but existing nodata values will no longer be considered nodata.

Answer (score 5):

with gdal:

1. `gdalbuildvrt -of GTIFF -srcnodata 0 input.tif myVrt.vrt`
2. `gdal_translate -of GTIFF -scale -a_nodata 0 myVrt.vrt output.tif`

beside this you can use raster calculator plugin or grass in qgis too. and arcpy [SetNull](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000007000000.htm) method.