# How to create transparent tif images using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have a number of tif files. These tif files have white background and black contours. What I want to achieve is to make this white background completely transparent. I tried a lot of `gdalwarp` commands, but to no avail:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata 255 -dstalpha ... # completely transparent. See no image
gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstalpha  ... # completely transparent. See no image
gdalwarp -srcnodata 255 ... # has no effect
gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 ... # also has no effect
```

It seems like I tried all possible combinations, but to no effect.

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

If I run this command with one of my tif files:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT 1-A.tif color.vrt
```

I get this as an output:

```
....
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
<Metadata domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE">
  <MDI key="NBITS">1</MDI>
</Metadata>
<NoDataValue>255</NoDataValue>
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
  <Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" />
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
</ColorTable>
<SimpleSource>
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">1-A.tif</SourceFilename>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5990" RasterYSize="5995" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="5990" BlockYSize="10" />
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5990" ySize="5995" />
  <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5990" ySize="5995" />
</SimpleSource>
```

....

It seems like my tif has only two colors - black and white. And what I want to achieve with GDAL (if it is possible), is to make white color completly transparent, so that when I publish my layer, I would see just black contours. Indeed I do not want to use Photoshop and cut all white color from all dozens of tifs. I hope, it can be done massively, using GDAL.

If it matters, my WMS service, which publishes all my layers, is configured with `transparent=true` and "format=image/png". So, it seems like I tried absolutely everything, but failed.

---

Here is some new information. This is what gdalinfo returns about one of the tifs (the real world tif published by Geoserver using Pyramid plugin):

> gdalinfo layer_537__01_01.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: layer_537__01_01.tif
Size is 2054, 2054
Coordinate System is:
...
...
Pixel Size = (0.169359008116544,-0.169359008116544)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=2054x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 0,0,0,255
    2: 0,0,0,255
    3: 0,0,0,255
    4: 0,0,0,255
    5: 0,0,0,255
    6: 0,0,0,255
    7: 0,0,0,255
    8: 0,0,0,255
    9: 0,0,0,255
   10: 0,0,0,255
   11: 0,0,0,255
   ...
```

I'm not sure, if it matters or not, but when I create the final mosaic with `gdal_retile.py`, I use `co "COMPRESS=JPEG"`. I do not know if it can effect the initial transparency of the geotiff.

**INPUT**

[image]

This is a typical tiff that I have ^^^.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve ^^^. I tried trillions of gdalwarp and gdal_translate and even gdalbuildvrt parameters, but completely to no avail, though the task at first glance looks absolutely trivial.

Do you know all those GDAL commands that I should apply to my tiff?

PS

This is how I can solve this task using QGIS:

[image]

And this is exactly what I want to achieve manually, using GDAL.

**Try # 1**

In this attempt I try gdalbuildvrt like so:

```
$ gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "255 255 255" -input_file_list tiles.txt mosaic.vrt
$ gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -co "NBITS=1" -co "COMPRESS=CCITTFAX4" mosaic.vrt layer.tiff
```

When I check mosaic.vrt, I see this contents:

```
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
<NoDataValue>255</NoDataValue>
<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
<ColorTable>
  <Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" />
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
  ...
  <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />
</ColorTable>
```

And when I check layer.tiff with gdalinfo, I see this:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: layer.tiff
Size is 11889, 11974
Coordinate System is:
...
Origin = ...
Pixel Size = (0.169326783070411,-0.169326783070411)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=CCITTFAX4
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ...
Lower Left  ...
Upper Right ...
Lower Right ...
Center      ...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  NoData Value=255
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=1
  Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 0,0,0,255
```

And this what I see, when I publish this tiff and visualize it on top of OpenStreetMap:

[image]

So, as you can see white color did't become transparent. And if it matters, these are parameters with which the layer is requested from WMS service:

[image]

So, this try again failed.

**UPDATE**

This is in fact what I want to achieve. I want to transform before.tiff to after.tiff (the way QGIS it did):

```
$ gdalinfo before.tiff
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: before.tiff
Size is 11889, 11974
Coordinate System is:
...
Origin = ...
Pixel Size = (0.169326783070411,-0.169326783070411)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=CCITTFAX4
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  NoData Value=255
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=1
  Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 0,0,0,255


$ gdalinfo after.tiff
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: after.tiff
Size is 11889, 11974
Coordinate System is:
...
Origin = ...
Pixel Size = (0.169326783070424,-0.169326783070413)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=11889x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=11889x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=11889x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=11889x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

The most important part, that changed is `Image Structure Metadata`.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot highlighting the issue? Are you working with single band or multiband images?

Comment: Are you attempting to set the NoData value? If so: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/41718/8104

Comment: In first two cases, when I publish these tifs what I see is just OpenStreetMap. In the last two cases, I just see tifs rendered on my OpenStreetMap background, without any effect being applied.

Comment: @Aaron. I have not tried it yet.

Comment: @Aaron. Would you be so kind to advise what magic number - 255 or 0 - should I use with `-a_nodata` config?

Comment: Could you please bring the image into a GIS and determine which pixel value you would like to convert to NoData?

Comment: Just a minute. I will check it.

Comment: So, I checked it. Inside ColorTable I see two entries: `<Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="255" />` and `<Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255" />`. If it matters `VRTRasterBand` tag looks like so: `<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">`

Comment: And what I want, is as simple as to make white color completely transparent, so that when I publish my map, I would see just black contours.

Comment: Are you working with spatial data? This sounds more like a Photoshop/GIMP issue.

Comment: I convert large hand-made area coverage into georeferenced tifs, using GDAL. And now the only problem is just transparency.

Comment: I would recommend distilling all of these comments as an edit to your question so that other readers can benefit from this new information.

Comment: White color is 255. Set this value as transparent.

Comment: This is an 8 bit raster data. To understand the pixel values in these rasters you can refer this link http://geospatialearth.in/earthbasics.php#8bit

Comment: @GeoSpatialEarth.in. I tried `gdalwarp -srcnodata 255` and `gdalwarp -srcnodata 255 -dstalpha`. In the first case, it has no effect. In the second case the tif gets completely transparent (both black and white color). Should I instead use `gdal_translate`?

Comment: Which viewer you are using? Or you are publish data as WMS service?

Comment: I publish it as as WMS service

Comment: Put one source image available for downloading and add link to your question.

Comment: @user30184. Unfortunatelly, these images are for internal use only :(. But in reality they are just black-white images. Nothing more.

Comment: You can perhaps create a fake file with similar structure. But a good start would be to add gdalinfo report of one original file into your question. You can hide file names, coordinates etc.

Comment: Thanks! I will update my question in a minute, with information from gdalinfo.

Comment: @user30184. Please, have a look. I made an update. Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55965/discussion-on-question-by-jacobian-how-to-create-transparent-tif-images-using-gd).

Comment: Does the solution here help:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25064/gdal-convert-specific-rgb-geotiff-color-to-transparent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) to add color to your tif file.

```
gdaldem color-relief input.tif style.txt -alpha output.tif
```

style.txt looks like this, each line having up to five values. First one is the raster's pixel value, next three are RGB values, and the fifth one is alpha, which is used for transparency - 255 means (by default) no transparency, 0 denotes fully transparent.

```
3500   white
2500   235:220:175
50%   190 185 135
700    240 250 150
0      50  180  50
nv     0   0   0   0
```

By default, it uses linear interpolation of color for other values. Use `-exact_color_entry` or `-nearest_color_entry` to avoid linear interpolation.

Comment: Wow, it works! And what if I have some arbitrary tiff (not just black-white) and want to make a particular color transparent. How would style.txt look like in this case?

Comment: @Jacobian Updated the answer, Please also check color-relief in http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html

Answer (score 3):

**GDAL & TIFF:**

Using GDAL utilities, but not gdalwarp specifically...

As per the answer at [GDAL: Convert specific RGB (GeoTIFF) color to transparent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25064/gdal-convert-specific-rgb-geotiff-color-to-transparent) , the following has worked for some users' GeoTIFFs.

Create a VRT for the image setting nodata for the pixel value that you want to be transparent:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "255 255 255" virtualimage.vrt input.tiff
```

Then create a new TIFF using the VRT as input:

```
gdal_translate virtualimage.vrt output.tiff
```

You'd have to check that "255 255 255" was in fact the correct pixel value for you to use, and adjust it to something else, if necessary.

**WMS:**

You commented that you are viewing through a WMS service.  Make sure that you are requesting PNGs from your WMS and not JPEGs.  JPEG cannot include transparency and the service will fill in any transparent pixels as either white or black when converting to JPEG (depending on the implementation).

Comment: As for WMS, I request PNGs and besides I set transparent=true

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunatelly, it does not work.

Comment: Can you post an image for which this does not work?    If your images are private, then create a new one, or modify an existing one that you can post.

Comment: I've just made my georeferenced tiff transparent in QGIS and published it with WMS and it's absolutely ok. I got exactly what I want to achieve. And I see (with the help of gdalinfo) that QGIS changed Image Structure Metadata of the initial tiff. I will provide details in my answer. Probably, you know how to transform the initial tiff and get this new Image Structure, using GDAL. Thanks!

Comment: I made an update. Please, have a look.