# Is it possible to reduce the size of a GeoTIFF file by removing its white pixels?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have a very huge GeoTIFF file (around 12GB).

[image]

Most of it is made with white spaces. So, I thought that if I removed these white spaces from it, the GeoTIFF file would reduce its size to something smaller than 12GB. After researching for a while, I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234057/173457) solution:

```bsh
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "0 0 0" virtualimage.vrt myTiffFile.tif
gdal_translate virtualimage.vrt outputTiffFile.tif
```

However, even though I can validate on QGIS that it has written `No Data` on whitespaces, the size of my GeoTIFF file is still 12GB. I'm not sure what's happening, can I reduce the size of a GeoTIFF layer by writing `No Data` to white pixels? If not, how can I reduce its size?

Comment: In uncompressed image every pixel takes the same amount of space. Contiguous areas with same pixel values can fortunately be compressed well even with lossless methods. Try `gdal_translate virtualimage.vrt outputTiffFile.tif -co compress:deflate -co tiled=yes` and feel the difference. Tile the image by the same, it is always a good default with any bigger images.

Comment: @user30184 Cool, it went from 12GB to 18MB in my case... Is there any downside of compressing it like this?

Comment: As @user30184 said, the command line calls a lossless compression algorithm. So there is no downside in the quality of the image. Depending on the relative speed of your processor vs. disk I/O, you might have a slowdown in loading the file because it has to be decompressed to be used in most applications. This will be most apparent on a system with a fast disk (eg, SSD) and slow CPU. You might actually come out ahead on a system with slow disk and fast CPU.

Comment: @user30184  - please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uncompressed TIFF files each pixel takes a fixed number of bits. However, TIFF files can be compressed and contiguous areas with uniform pixel values like the nodata-area in your image can be compressed extremely well even with lossless compression method like "deflate" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate.

Basic command for creating a deflate compressed and tiled image from a GDAL virtual raster file with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff  -co compress=deflate -co tiled=yes virtualimage.vrt outputTiffFile.tif
```

Tiling makes it possible for client programs to access small areas of interest from a large tiff file efficiently without reading all too much unnecessary pixels.

Answer (score 1):

To go along with the answer by user30184, adding the following will further decrease your file size:

```
-co PREDICTOR=2
```

Reference:
https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/